# hscolour: Colouring only a sub-expression

Tags: haskell, syntax-highlighting

Suppose I want to tag syntactic constructs of a monadic action. Is there a simpler (cleaner) definition of `colour` than this:

```
import Language.Haskell.HsColour.CSS
import Language.Haskell.HsColour.Classify

colour :: String -> String
colour = concat . map renderToken . unwrap . tokenise . wrap where
    wrap :: String -> String
    wrap = (prefix ++)

    unwrap :: [a] -> [a]
    unwrap = drop (length (tokenise prefix))

    prefix :: String
    prefix = "x = do "
```

To me it seems that `hscolour` always assumes starting at top-level. That is why without `wrap` it tags the first token as `definition` which is clearly something I don't want as I intend to pass only an expression that can occur in a `do` block.

Comment: Did you intend to write: `colour = concat . unwrap . map renderToken . tokenise . wrap` ?

Comment: actually no, although it is almost the same, there is no reason to map over the elements that are dropped

Comment: yeah - I see that now

Comment: Sorry - spotted a slight error in my answer so I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the token stream differs
when you use your `colour` function vs. `tokenise`
on the input:

```
a <- getLine; return $ words a

with colour          with just tokenise
-----------          ------------------
(Varid,"a")          (Definition,"a")
(Space," ")          (Space," ")
(Keyglyph,"<-")      (Keyglyph,"<-")
(Space," ")          (Space," ")
(Varid,"getLine")    (Varid,"getLine")
(Layout,";")         (Layout,";")
(Space," ")          (Space," ")
(Varid,"return")     (Varid,"return")
(Space," ")          (Space," ")
(Varop,"$")          (Varop,"$")
(Space," ")          (Space," ")
(Varid,"words")      (Varid,"words")
(Space," ")          (Space," ")
(Varid,"a")          (Varid,"a")
```

So the only difference is that the first
`Varid` token has been changed to a `Definition` token.

In fact, this is exactly what the `markDefs` function does -
it changes a leading `Varid` token to a `Definition` [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hscolour-1.23/docs/src/Language-Haskell-HsColour-Classify.html#tokenise):

```
markDefs :: [(TokenType, String)] -> [(TokenType, String)]
markDefs [] = []
markDefs ((Varid, s) : rest) = (Definition, s) : continue rest
markDefs ((Varop, ">") : (Space, " ") : (Varid, d) : rest) =
    (Varop, ">") : (Space, " ") : (Definition, d) : continue rest
markDefs rest = continue rest
```

And note that `markDefs` is the only way a `Definition` token may be created. Any `Varid` which appears at the beginning of a line will be changed to a `Definition` token.

So an alternative to your approach is to just change all
`Definition` tokens back to a `Varid`.

```
colour' = concat . map renderToken . map fixup . tokenise  where
  where fixup (Definition, d) = (Varid, d)
        fixup t                = t
```